# Missing threads data when debugging Node.js in the IntelliJ

Tags: node.js, multithreading, intellij-idea, monitoring

I am using IntelliJ as IDE and I shifted from Java to Node.js. Any idea how to view threads' data in the Debug window (where the frames are) like when debugging Java processes?
I understand that the js code and the event loop are running on a single thread, but I expect to see worker threads of libuv when doing file operations.

More details:

- IntelliJ Ultimate version 2018.3
- Node version v12.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should normally see them when the execution is suspended on breakpoint, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/10/webstorm-2018-3-eap-6/:

[image]

I'm not however sure that it works with Node.js 12.14 - the IDE version you are using is quite old, it was released long before the Node.js 12.14.x release

Comment: correct. I upgraded to 2020.1.1 and now I see threads data in _Debug_ window. Thanks!